# SQL Join with multiple row condition in second table

Tags: sql, join

I have a question on SQL join which involve multiple condition in second joined table. Below is the table details

### Table 1

pId     status       keyVal 
----   -------    ------   
100         1               45     
101        1               46

### Table 2

pId          mode           modeVal 
100             2                       5 
100             3                        6

101             2                        7
101             3                        8

I have above two tables and I am trying to join based on below condition to get pId's

pId's which has keyVal = 45 and status = 1 joined with table2 which has mode = 2 and modeVal 5 and mode =3 and modeVal = 6

the result I am expecting is to return pid = 100

Can you please help me with a join query ?

Comment: `FROM table1 JOIN table2 on table1.pld = table2.pld WHERE table2.modeVal IN (5,6) AND table2.mode IN (2,3)` I guess, join condition is only `pld`, in your where clause you put the other condition for the expected result

Comment: will it work for the specific combination of (mode=2 and modeValue=5) and (mode=3 and modeValue=6) ? The query should return pId iff both the conditions are satisfied and in pair (2,5) and (3,6)

Comment: Not at all, the IN operator is like OR operator, only one of the values is needed to return result. In your case you could use exactly the thing you mentioned `WHERE (mode=2 and modeValue=5) or (mode=3 and modeValue=6)`

Comment: Are you asking for a match on _at least_ those two combinations, or _exactly_ those two combinations and none other?

Comment: But this will return pId = 100 even if row 2 in Table 2 is not present. I want 100 to be returned only if row 1 and row 2 in Table 2 present ( AND condition).

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson I am looking for exactly those two combinations and none other

Comment: @vinayknl Any particular SQL dialect? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to count that the number of rows found is 2, of which 2 are matching the condition;

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table2)
SELECT t1."pId" 
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN cte t2 ON t1."pId" = t2."pId"
WHERE t1."status" = 1 AND t1."keyVal" = 45
GROUP BY t1."pId"
HAVING SUM(
  CASE WHEN t2."mode"=2 AND t2."modeVal"=5 OR t2."mode"=3 AND t2."modeVal"=6 
       THEN 1 END) = 2 AND COUNT(*)=2
```

If the values in t2 are already distinct, you can just remove the `cte` and select directly from Table2.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/087ed/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columns
FROM table1 a, table2 B
WHERE a.pid = B.pid
    AND a.keyval = 45
    AND a.status = 1
    AND (
        (B.mode = 2 AND B.modeval = 5)
        OR 
        (B.mode = 3 AND B.modeval = 6)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work for you perfectly

```
select distinct table1.pid FROM table1 JOIN table2 
on table1.pid = table2.pid 
WHERE table2.modeValue IN (5,6) AND table2.mode IN (2,3) AND table1.keyVal=45 and table1.status=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but will it work for the specific combination of (mode=2 and modeValue=5) and (mode=3 and modeValue=6) ?

Comment: you have to do this then :  WHERE 
(table2.modeValue  =6 AND table2.mode =3  AND table1.keyVal=45 and table1.status=1)
or (table2.modeValue  =5 AND table2.mode =2  AND table1.keyVal=45 and table1.status=1);